# Line integral with $dx$ and $dy$ - geometric interpretation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, curves

This question is about curvilinear integration.

The first page here, it says what the geometric meaning is when the line integral is taken with this $ds$, where this $ds$ indicates the line integral is w.r.t. the arc length.

https://www.geogebra.org/m/fRHzaMnF
https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx

So this meaning is basically the area of a **curtain** hanging down from the surface $F(x,y)$ to the curve $C$. I can understand this, it sounds intuitive enough.

OK... But I also read about a similar line integrals only with $dx$ and $dy$ instead of $ds$.

$$\int_C F(x,y)\ dx$$

$$\int_C F(x,y)\ dy$$

I know their definitions, they are clear to me.

But I wonder what their geometric meaning would be.

Also, I wonder if these two ($dx$ and $dy$) curvilinear or line integrals are somehow related to each other.

Comment: Hint 1: write more generally
$$
\int_C F_1\,dx+F_2\,dy
$$
and consider that $(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt})$ is the tangent to the curve $C\,.$

Hint 2: do the same with
$$
\int_C F_2\,dx-F_1\,dy
$$
and consider that $(-\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dx}{dt})$ is the normal vector to the curve $C\,.$